# How do I get the results from my database query?

Tags: node.js, express, mariadb

I have an express app which performs the following mariadb query:

```
// GET (init)
app.get('/init', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const result = await db.pool.query("SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT (line)) FROM db.lines");
        console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
    } catch (err) {
        throw err;
    }
});
```

The result I get from this query is printed in console as:

```
[{"COUNT(DISTINCT (line))":8}]
```

This is great and it's the correct data. My problem is I can't figure out how the hell I access this data?!

I know if I had a `query select book from bookcase where title = "A Game of Thrones"` I could simply put in `JSON.stringify(result.book) or result[0].book`... but how does it work with a count distinct query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do

```js
result[0]["COUNT(DISTINCT (line))"]
```

You can also us AS keyword to name returned data e.g

```sql
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT (line)) AS count FROM db.lines
```

and it would return you

```json
[{"count":8}]
```

You could then use

```js
result[0].count
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. Will accept your answer once it lets me.